# Extra space with libertine package

Tags: fonts, spacing, pdftex, libertine

I'm trying to compile this simple document with PdfLateX-MikTeX 2.9, but there's an unwanted extra space between regualr and bold sentences.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % font

\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \textbf{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,} quis nostrud exercitation ullamco \textbf{laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat}. Duis aute irure dolor in \textbf{reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem seems to be due to `libertine` package: indeed commenting the package the problem disappears. 
Any idea? Thanks.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.12.9)  9 DEC 2016 17:26
entering extended mode
**document.tex
(D:\Desktop\document.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, arabic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, ngerman-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usenglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 43.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty"
Package: libertine 2014/11/25 (Bob Tennent) Supports Libertine and Biolinum fonts for all LaTeX engines.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count87
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty"
Package: textcomp 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 71.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def"
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 266.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 281.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 282.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 283.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 284.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 285.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 286.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 287.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 288.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 289.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 290.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 291.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 292.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 293.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 294.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 295.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 296.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 297.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 298.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 299.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 300.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 301.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 302.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 303.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 304.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 305.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 306.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 307.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 308.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 309.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 310.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 311.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 312.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 313.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 314.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 315.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 316.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 317.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 318.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 319.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 320.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 321.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 322.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 323.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 324.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 325.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 326.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 327.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 328.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 329.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 330.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 331.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 332.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 333.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 335.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 336.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 337.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 338.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 339.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 340.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mweights\mweights.sty"
Package: mweights 2016/12/04 (Bob Tennent) Support package for multiple-weight 
font packages. 
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bfseries on input line 21.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mdseries on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 56.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 75.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontaxes\fontaxes.sty"
Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 478.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\libertine\LinLibertine_I.tex"))
(D:\Desktop\document.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 6.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd"
File: ts1cmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+LinuxLibertineT-TLF on 
input line 6.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\libertine\t1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd"
File: T1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd 2012/11/26 (autoinst) Font definitions for T1/Li
nuxLibertineT-TLF.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 6.
\c@mv@tabular=\count88
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count89
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 7.
 [1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

]
(D:\Desktop\document.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
libertine.sty    2014/11/25 (Bob Tennent) Supports Libertine and Biolinum fonts
 for all LaTeX engines.
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
mweights.sty    2016/12/04 (Bob Tennent) Support package for multiple-weight fo
nt packages. 
 fontenc.sty
fontaxes.sty    2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LinLibertine_I.tex
  ts1cmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
t1linuxlibertinet-tlf.fd
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2016 strings out of 493921
 34761 string characters out of 3147279
 67328 words of memory out of 3000000
 5338 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 14919 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,33p,517b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_nh77jq.enc}{C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_76gpa5.enc}<C:/Program Fi
les/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertineT.pfb><C:/Program Files
/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertineTB.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 165498 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Bug in `mweights`, there are a few other questions about it

Comment: I don't see the spaces in texlive (Ubuntu 16.10)

Comment: @egreg: How they solved it?

Comment: @Andrea You can see the (temporary) workaround in the question linked as duplicate. Actually, today a new version was included in TeX Live, but it has another bug. Stay tuned with the linked question, where I'll announce the good update.